# How can I upgrade minimal install?

Tags: apt, upgrade, 18.04, minimal-install

Just installed [18.04](/questions/tagged/18.04) using the minimal install. A great option!

But then I ran `sudo apt update` and it showed `179 packages can be upgraded`. I suspect that it will then add back all the stuff that I don't need.

How do I just upgrade the current minimal installation? Or, how do I select what is to be upgraded or the converse, not upgraded?

Comment: If you run `apt update` again, and read the output carefully, you will see how to list the upgradable packages. Use `dpkg -l | grep <packagename>` to wander that list and prove to yourself that it's merely and upgrade to an already-installed package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you use the proper application (dpkg/apt/apt-get/aptitude/synaptic/Software Center) to install and uninstall deb packages, the dpkg database of installed packages will be accurate.

As long as the dpkg database is accurate, `apt upgrade` will only upgrade installed software. It will NOT restore previously-uninstalled packages.

Comment: Ahhh, OK, I saw "179" and thought that might be all packages normally installed on a full system. But I just did an **apt list --installed** on my work PC and got 2697 installed. Obviously, now, that 179 **is** minimal. Thanks again.